# React Native - How to create URL scheme for my application?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I want to redirect the user from my website to my application. I explore this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking) but I am failed to know how to create a `link` or `deep link` for my application that will redirect the user to my application and this link will be understood by the application.

Can anyone tell me a little bit about the linking and deep linking and also teach me the steps how to create a `link` or `deep link` for my app? What is the process & method of creating the URL scheme for your application? I don't have any background in `Java` or `Objective-C`. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Deep link can be set up programmatically by using these methods:

For IOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app

For Android: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Both documentations detailed how you can deep link your mobile application